# Se repite la consulta

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

tengo un problema con el siguiente codigo, básicamente es que en mi página hay 3 buscadores, el problema es que los 3 me sacan la misma consulta sql, aunque estas sean distintas:

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
<asp:Panel CssClass="form-group" ID="Panel1" runat="server" Visible="true">
    <asp:Label Text="Tema" runat="server" CssClass="col-md-2 control-label" AssociatedControlID="ddlAutores" />
        <div class="col-md-10">
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAutores" runat="server" data-live-search="true" CssClass="form-control selectpicker" AutoPostBack="true" DataSourceID="SqlTemas" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Submit_Click" DataValueField="Value">
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                    </div>
            <asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="SqlDataSource1" ConnectionString='<%$ConnectionStrings:DEFAULT %>' SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT DOCUMENTO.ID_DOCUMENTO AS Value FROM DOCUMENTO INNER JOIN TEMAS ON TEMAS.ID_TEMA = DOCUMENTO.ID_TEMAP WHERE (TEMAS.ID_TEMA = 2)">
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
     </asp:Panel>


<div class="form-horizontal">
<asp:Panel CssClass="form-group" ID="Panel1" runat="server" Visible="true">
    <asp:Label Text="Tema" runat="server" CssClass="col-md-2 control-label" AssociatedControlID="ddlAutores" />
        <div class="col-md-10">
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAutores" runat="server" data-live-search="true" CssClass="form-control selectpicker" AutoPostBack="true" DataSourceID="SqlTemas" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Submit_Click" DataValueField="Value">
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                    </div>
            <asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="SqlDataSource1" ConnectionString='<%$ConnectionStrings:DEFAULT %>' SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT DOCUMENTO.ID_DOCUMENTO AS Value FROM DOCUMENTO INNER JOIN AUTORES_DOCUMENTO ON DOCUMENTO.ID_DOCUMENTO = AUTORES_DOCUMENTO.ID_DOCUMENTO WHERE AUTORES_DOCUMENTO.ID_AUTOR = 1;">
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
     </asp:Panel>
```

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
<asp:Panel CssClass="form-group" ID="Panel2" runat="server" Visible="true">
        <asp:Label Text="Lugar" runat="server" CssClass="col-md-2 control-label" AssociatedControlID="ddlFondos" />
                <div class="col-md-10">
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" data-live-search="true" CssClass="form-control selectpicker" AutoPostBack="true" DataSourceID="SqlTemas" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Submit_Click" DataValueField="Value">
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                    </div>
            <asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="SqlDataSource2" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:DEFAULT %>' SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT DOCUMENTO.ID_DOCUMENTO AS Value FROM DOCUMENTO INNER JOIN TEMAS ON TEMAS.ID_TEMA = DOCUMENTO.ID_TEMAP INNER JOIN AUTORES_DOCUMENTO ON DOCUMENTO.ID_DOCUMENTO = AUTORES_DOCUMENTO.ID_DOCUMENTO WHERE ((AUTORES_DOCUMENTO.ID_AUTOR = @idAutor) OR (@idAutor IS NULL)) UNION SELECT 0 AS Value">
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
</asp:Panel>
```

Gracias de antemano :)

Comment: Los dos primeros no tienen exactamente la misma consulta?

Comment: si perdon, esque estaba probando, ya esta editado

Comment: cual es el que te muestra de los tres?

Comment: El primero, ponga lo que ponga en los otros siempre me sale lo del primero

Comment: puede ser `DataSourceID="SqlTemas"` que en los tres lo tienes igual

Comment: Vale si menuda tontuna jeje Gracias ^^